# Drag and Drop Sort in Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have tag list with default sort by desc. Users can drag and drop tags.

How to sort by user drag and drop to retrieve later.

I am using elasticsearch and nodejs for that.

**Update my solution:**

I plan to add 1 field (data type float) so called default order (possibly timestamp time) of tags. When the user drags and drops, the word FE will be sent to the top and bottom positions of the card being dragged. Then I will update the new position of the dragged card as the average of the 2 positions above and below it.

Comment: it will be great if you can add what you have tried till now. what kind of query you have tried in Elasticsearch ? Drop and drag is UI functionlity and you need to write logic at frontend side to make query.

Comment: i plan to add 1 field (data type float) so called default order (possibly timestamp time) of tags. When the user drags and drops, the word FE will be sent to the top and bottom positions of the card being dragged. Then I will update the new position of the dragged card as the average of the 2 positions above and below it.